# how to detect touch on rotated sprite in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have rotated sprite to 90. I checked the touch location of the rotated sprite as follows:

```
matchsprite.rotation=90;

CGRect r=CGRectMake(matchstick.position.x, matchstick.position.y, matchstick.contentSize.height,matchstick.contentSize.width);
if(CGRectContainsPoint(r, location))    
    NSLog(@"Hii");
```

What is the error in this code? I didnt get "Hii". How to detect whether we tap that rotated sprite or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two CCNode extension (category) methods I've added to the [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) game engine:

```
-(BOOL) containsPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect bbox = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize_.width, contentSize_.height);
    CGPoint locationInNodeSpace = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(bbox, locationInNodeSpace);
}

-(BOOL) containsTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
    CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CGPoint locationGL = [director convertToGL:[touch locationInView:director.openGLView]];
    return [self containsPoint:locationGL];
}
```

Testing if a point is on a sprite (or label or any other node) then is as simple as:

```
UITouch* uiTouch = [touches anyObject];
if ([aSprite containsTouch:uiTouch])
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position property of ccsprite gives you the centre coordinate and not the top left corner position.

you can get the rect made like this

```
CGRect r=CGRectMake(matchstick.position.x - matchstick.contentSize.width / 2, matchstick.position.y + matchstick.contentSize.height / 2, matchstick.contentSize.height, matchstick.contentSize.width);
```

I am not sure if you need to subtract or add half of the width but i think you can do a little R&D on it.

Comment: i have given the anchor point to matchstick as matchstick.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);

Comment: if not then use [[ccdirector shareddirector] convertToGLPoint:location], i m not sure if the name of the function is correct.

Comment: yes i did. it works fine, if the sprite is not rotated. dont know y it is not working if we rotate the sprite.

Comment: first rotate the sprite and then set the anchor point that is what causing the problem.